# Accessing a list entry and showing its values

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
(.#.) :: [a] -> Integer -> a                  -- 1-indexing with 'Integer'

xs .#. j = xs !! (fromIntegral $ j-1)
```

---

```
showIntegers :: [Integer] -> String

showIntegers r = let

      str = concat $ "List: " : [r (.#.) j | j <- [1..length r]]
```

How can I show `r (.#.) j` as a `Char`/`String` rather than an integer? I tried using `show`, but it gave me an error.

Here is an example of how I used `show`:

```
str = concat $ "List: " : [show $ r (.#.) j | j <- [1..length r]]
```

Example input and output:

```
> showIntegers [1,2,3]
List: 1 2 3
```

Comment: 1. How did you use `show`and get an error? 2. Give an example of your wanted string for `showIntegers [1,2,3]`

Comment: What error?  `*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large` by any chance?  Lists are zero-indexed, so you probably want `[0..length r - 1]`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I forgot to change the fact that I used 1 indexing rather than 0 indexing, I predefined a rule, I guess I should call it that, to change that.

Comment: `($)` has higher precedence than `(!!)`, so you should simply do `[show r !! j | j <- [1..length r]]`

Comment: @MichalSeweryn: That would convert the list to a string and then take the index of the resultant string. Also use \` to denote a code segment.

Comment: Using `r !! i` to access the elements of a list in Haskell is the last resort, since it is quite inefficient (lists are not arrays). Using a list comprehension over `[1 .. length r]` is a common antipattern. Don't write `[f (r !! i) | i <-[0..length r-1]]`, use instead `[f x | x<-r]` or `map f r`.

Comment: As an aside, there's no reason to use Integer if you immediately convert them to Int anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use [Data.List.intercalate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220986/is-there-any-haskell-function-to-concatenate-list-with-separator) or even better use [unwords](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:unwords).

```
import Data.List
showIntegers :: [Integer] -> String
showIntegers r = "List: " ++ intercalate " " $ map show r
--showIntegers r = "List: " ++ unwords $ map show r
```

EDIT: In either case you should avoid using `!!` especially to enumerate the original list.

First I would get rid of `.#.` it is just going to confuse you to use a different numbering system, best to rip that bandaid off.

Next realize that `[show $ r !! j <- 0 .. length r - 1]` is the same as `map show r` (and the latter is standard).

Now going with that you have: `concat $ "List: " : (map show r)` which creates `List: 123` because we lost the spaces.

We could reproduce the spaces but what is the difference between using `intercalate` and `concat`? Honestly the best solution without using `intercalate` would be to reproduce `intercalate` (whose source code is available on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#intercalate)).

Comment: Would it be possible without predefined functions? I'm trying to understand how Haskell works and if I just use that it wouldn't help me understand how things work.

Comment: also, my professor insists that I use 1 indexing. I'm not sure why and I'm used to 0 indexing but I have to comply.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that `unwords` is the special case of `intercalate " "`, and `unwords` exists in `Prelude` already, you don't need to import `Data.List`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parenthesis around `(.#.)` and it works.

If you have an infix operator `!#$` , with something before and after it, e.g.  `x !#$ y`, you must not use parentheses. In the other cases, add parentheses, like in the type declaration.

(this technically answers the question, but Guvante's advice is better.)