# Haskell - Writing array to file without square brackets

Tags: performance, haskell, io, linked-list

In my program, I generate a list of numbers:

```
data = [2,3,2,5,2,7,2,3,2,11 ... ]
```

Now I want to write this list of numbers as a single-line comma-separated string in a file. I know I can use `writeFile` combined with `Show`:

```
writeFile "data.txt" $ show $ data
```

However, this will also print the square brackets at the beginning and end. Now I could remove the first and last characters from the string `Show data` by using `reverse`, but this is inefficient. At some point, the program is already traversing the list in order to write the characters to the file, so how can I make sure it doesn't write the first and last characters without doing an unnecessary traversal?

Will this do the job most efficiently?

```
writeFile "data.txt" $ drop 1 $ takeWhile (\c -> c/= ']') $ show data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is fine, but I think a neater way is not to use `show` on the list, but to show each element and put in the commas yourself, like this:

```
writeFile "data.txt" . intercalate "," . map show $ [1, 2, 3]
```

`intercalate` is from `Data.List`.

(by the way: you can't call a variable `data`, because that's a keyword)

Comment: Right you are about the `data`. Hadn't thought about that when writing the pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

You have lot of way for doing this! Your data are converted to strings, and, you can now use them:

In your case, you can write your code like this (each element of the list is read one time and directly converted)

```haskell
writeFile "data.txt" $ Data.List.foldl (\x y -> x ++ show y ++ ",") "" data
```

and without last comma:

```haskell
writeFile "data.txt" $ Data.List.tail $ Data.List.foldl (\x y -> x ++ "," ++ show y) "" data
```

or using intercalate from Data.List

```haskell
 Data.List.intercalate "," $ Data.List.map (\x -> show x) data
```

Similar questions are on stackoverflow:

- [Is there any haskell function to concatenate list with separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220986/is-there-any-haskell-function-to-concatenate-list-with-separator)

Comment: Nice. Note that the fold approach will generate a trailing comma, while intercalate does not.

Comment: Yep, sorry, Solution here: `Data.List.tail $ Data.List.foldl (\x y -> x ++ "," ++ show y) "" data`.

Comment: `foldl` is a bad choice here.  Try it in ghci on `[1..1000000]` and watch it crawl.  You're forcing `(++)` to associate to the left and that makes it do quadratic work repeatedly traversing `"1"` then `"1,2"` then `"1,2,3"` etc.  Use `foldr`.

Comment: and if I do something like that? `Data.List.foldr (\x y -> "," ++ show x ++ y ) "" data`