# How to concatenate list into a string with separator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function which takes a list and returns a concatenated string consisting of all strings from the input list, separated with spaces '', e.g.

`setTogether ["aaa", "bbb", "c", "cc"] == "aaa bbb c cc"`

`setTogether ["aaa"] == "aaa"`

with the type signature: `setTogether :: [String] -> String`

```
setTogether :: [String] -> String
setTogether ls = [x | x <- ls]
```

^as you can see I'm kind of lost! Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Edit: I'm not supposed to use "words" or "unwords"

Comment: `[x | x <- ls]` is simply the same as `ls`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any haskell function to concatenate list with separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220986/is-there-any-haskell-function-to-concatenate-list-with-separator)

Comment: Do you just need a function that does this (in which case, it's a duplicate of the question Silver Rampart linked to), or are you required to *write* the function yourself as an assignment?

Comment: Probably should've mentioned that! I need to write the function; I'm not allowed to use words/unwords @chepner

Comment: Even if you need to write the function (which is `intercalate " "`) there are a bunch of examples of `intercalate` from scratch in anwsers to the question that Silver Rampart linked

Answer (score 2):

```
setTogether :: [String] -> String
setTogether ss = intercalate " " ss
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: Your question doesn't mention needing `[` and `]` in the answer. For that, `setTogether = intercalate " "` would be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, true! Thanks :) Editing answer now @chepner