# How to convert all elements of list into numbers?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, numbers

input : my_list = [1,2,3]
output : 1,2,3

How to convert?

Comment: Are you asking how to print `1,2,3` from that list? Then `",".join(str(i) for i in ints)` Otherwise, your list is already a list of ints. no conversion is required.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention which language

```
const my_list = [1,2,3]
console.log(my_list.join()); -> this one will return 1,2,3 string
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
my_list = [1,2,3] 
ints = [int(item) for item in my_list]
print(ints)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your expected output, did you intend to convert the list to a comma separated string? Is it in Javascript? Python? Haskell?

Already answered for [javascript here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list) and [python here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string) and [Haskell here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220986/is-there-any-haskell-function-to-concatenate-list-with-separator)

---

For Javascript using the [join method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const elements = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(elements.join());
// expected output: "1,2,3"

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: "123"

console.log(elements.join('-'));
// expected output: "1-2-3"
```